# Polynomial in terms of coordinate functionals

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, banach-spaces

I am trying to write a m-homogeneous polynomial in terms of coordinate functionals by using permutations in $S_m$. I am not sure about how should I go for getting this representation? Here,  $P \in \mathcal P\left({ }^m E\right)$ denotes the vector space of all m-homogeneous polynomials from $E$ into $\Bbb C$ And $S_m$ is the symmetric group.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What are the $x_i$ in the expression $A(x_1,...,x_m)$?

Answer (score 2):

A hint.

If $x=(x_1,x_2,...)\in E=\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ (namely, $\sum_{n\geq 1}|x_n|<+\infty$) then
$$
P(x)=\prod_{i=1}^m x_i=x_1\cdots x_m.
$$
For example, $m=1$, $P(x)=x_1$. How to maximize $|P(x)|=|x_1|$ under the constraint $\sum_{n\geq 1} |x_n|=|x_1|+\sum_{n\geq 2} |x_n|=1$?

If $m=2$, $P(x)=x_1x_2$. How to maximize $|P(x)|=|x_1x_2|$ under the constraint $\sum_{n\geq 1} |x_n|=|x_1|+|x_2|+\sum_{n\geq 3} |x_n|=1$?

It should be clear that for a general $m\geq 1$ you want to maximize $x_1\cdots x_m$ over nonnegative real numbers $x_1,...,x_m$ under the constraint $x_1+\cdots+x_m=1$. This is a classical problem (one has to saturate the AM-GM inequality).

Comment: What part is not clear?

Comment: If $x$ is an element of $E=\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ then $x$ is a sequence of complex numbers $x_1,x_2,...$ such that the series $\sum_n x_n$ converges absolutely.
The coordinate (linear) functional $\xi_k:E\to\mathbb C$ just extracts the $k$th term in the sequence: $\xi_k(x)=x_k$.
The statement that $P(x)=A(x,...,x)$ is not necessary to compute $\|P\|=m^{-m}$.